# Why should we use -m in a git commit command?

Tags: git, git-commit

```
git commit -m "my commit"
```

We used this command to add the commit to my Github repo.

What does this "-m" mean?

Comment: [`git commit -m`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--mltmsggt)

Comment: git commit --help will show you what it's for

Comment: You should use it if you want to, and not use it if you don't want to. It's just a way of working with commit messages. Note that `-m <msg>` implies `--no-edit` if you don't specifically specify `--edit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-m` means you are writing a message. If you write your message without the `-m` it will return an error. The message will be found in the commit section on Github!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Do a `git commit --help`

[image]

`-m` is for the message. This will appear on your commit history

example: `git commit -m "update to match android ui."`

[image]